# How to stop text from overlapping CSS?

Tags: css, html

Im creating a website for college and Im not sure how to stop text from overlapping when I make the web browser smaller. This is what I mean:

(not overlapping)
[image: t]

(overlapping)
[image: tt]

Here is my jsfiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/RC4Ar/)

```
.words {
font-family:apple;
font-size:20px;
max-width:800px;
height:190px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:42%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't declare a height. Allow the text itself to force the container to expand.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help it has worked!

Comment: Sorry i was being stupid then, I have gotten rid of it and now it works thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are adding the `words` class to the paragraph tags (without your html, we can only guess), you simply need to remove the `height` declaration.

```
.words {
font-family: apple;
font-size: 20px;
max-width: 800px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 42%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your fiddle example, I would change the title_bar to have a min height instead of a fixed height. This will allow it to be responsive instead of overlapping over the following text.

```
#title_bar {
    margin-top:78px;
    left:-17px;
    width:101.5%;
    min-height:30px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    top:-70px;
    z-index:3;
    border: 3px rgba(255, 105, 180, 1) solid;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, right top, color-stop(0, #5977FF), color-stop(1, #59C5FF));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RC4Ar/1/)

Comment: Ahh thanks dude, that makes my website look 10x better! Thanks again!